# h2o.init error due to xgboost

Tags: r, h2o, xgboost

I use the h2o package in R (Windows machine) and can't initialize it by h2o.init after updating the package recently.

The error message is produced below. I guess the cause of the problem is that h2o xgboost doesn't support Windows (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html). Is my guess correct? If so, how can I ask the h2o package to exclude xgboost in initialization to avoid the error?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b30)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................Cannot load library from path lib/windows_32/xgboost4j_gpu.dll
Cannot load library from path lib/xgboost4j_gpu.dll
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Cannot load library from path lib/windows_32/xgboost4j_omp.dll
Cannot load library from path lib/xgboost4j_omp.dll
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Cannot load library from path lib/windows_32/xgboost4j_minimal.dll
Cannot load library from path lib/xgboost4j_minimal.dll
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
07-27 11:24:19.197 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Cannot initialize XGBoost backend! Xgboost (enabled GPUs) needs: 
07-27 11:24:19.197 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO:   - CUDA 8.0
07-27 11:24:19.197 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: XGboost (minimal version) needs: 
07-27 11:24:19.197 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO:   - GCC 4.7+
07-27 11:24:19.197 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: For more details, run in debug mode: `java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j.properties -jar h2o.jar`
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Build git branch: rel-wright
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Build git hash: 24410cf788602f231fd699037bdaff0ad20b4d1a
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-3.20.0.1-26-g24410cf
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Build age: 1 month and 11 days
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Built on: '2018-06-15 18:39:02'
07-27 11:24:19.230 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git branch: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git hash: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git describe: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build project version: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built by: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built on: (unknown)
07-27 11:24:19.231 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Processed H2O arguments: [-name, H2O_started_from_R_534474366_nnz606, -ip, 127.0.0.1, -port, 54321, -ice_root, C:/Users/534474~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCc9kQI]
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 4
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 15.5 MB
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 989.9 MB
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.7.0_51 (from Oracle Corporation)
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-Xmx1g, -ea]
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: OS version: Windows 7 6.1 (x86)
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 4.00 GB
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1532705056352
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: User name: '534474366'
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: IPv6 stack selected: false
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1), 127.0.0.1
07-27 11:24:19.232 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:net0 (WAN Miniport (SSTP))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:net1 (WAN Miniport (L2TP))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:net2 (WAN Miniport (PPTP))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:ppp0 (WAN Miniport (PPPOE))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth0 (WAN Miniport (IPv6))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth1 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth2 (WAN Miniport (IP))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:ppp1 (RAS Async Adapter)
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:net3 (WAN Miniport (IKEv2))
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth3 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM), 10.95.108.135
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth4 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM-McAfee NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth5 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.233 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth6 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth7 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-McAfee NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth8 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth9 (WAN Miniport (IP)-McAfee NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth10 (WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth11 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-McAfee NDIS Light-Weight Filter-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      INFO: Network interface is down: name:eth12 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)
07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      FATAL: On /127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port PORT and try again. 
[1] "127.0.0.1"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 54321: Connection refused"
curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED Response**

If you look at the bottom of your error message:

`07-27 11:24:19.234 127.0.0.1:54321       14488  main      FATAL: On /127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port PORT and try again. 
[1] "127.0.0.1"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 54321: Connection refused"
curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
[1] 1`

You can see that the issue should not be related to XGBoost. In addition, the expected behavior on Windows is that XGBoost is automatically disabled and no action is needed on your part.

To fix your problem try specifying a different port using the `port =` parameter in `h2o.init()` to see if you can get `h2o.init()` to work for you.

**Original Response**

I will leave the prior answer up in case it helps others who come across the question of disabling xgboost:

you can disable xgboost by setting `-Dsys.ai.h2o.ext.core.toggle.XGBoost` to `False`

please see the documentation for more details: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html#disabling-xgboost

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that link, Lauren. I actually saw that webpage from H2O but had no idea how to do it within R. The option "-Dsys.ai.h2o.ext.core.toggle.XGBoost" is not an argument in h2o.init(). The suggestions in that webpage seems to be for use in direct H2O or Hadoop H2O drivers which I don't have experiences yet. Maybe I should clarify my question to be how to disable xgboost in h2o initialization inside R running on Windows machine. Sorry for the imprecision in my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Lauren. Yes, you are right. My problem was not due to XGBoost. The problem actually goes away after I restarted my machine (I previously only tried restarting R and the problem was still there. Out of frustration I gave up and restarted my machine this morning due to something else. But then h2o works too =). Thanks for your help Lauren. My lesson is that not just restarting R but also restarting the machine after updating h2o to avoid initialization error. Hope my question here is helpful for other people who encounter the same problem.